# Why is the first element of my WFS layer None instead of a feature?

Tags: python, ogr, osgeo

I have made a WFS connection and got a layer from it. I want to use the first feature from that layer.

```
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("WFS")
wfs_url = "WFS:http://example.com/wfs"
wfs = driver.Open(wfs_url)
layer = wfs.GetLayerByName("mylayer")
```

Now I want to use the first feature from it.

```
>>> print(sessionlayer[0])
None
>>> type(sessionlayer[0])
<class 'NoneType'>
```

Why does `layer[0]` not give me the first feature?
What is that `layer[0]` element?

If I loop over the features of the layer, I do not get that weird None element:

```
for i, feature in enumerate(sessionlayer):
  print(i, feature)
```

gives me

```
0 <osgeo.ogr.Feature; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRFeatureShadow *' at 0x7f33cca12690> >
1 <osgeo.ogr.Feature; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'OGRFeatureShadow *' at 0x7f33cca126c0> >
...
...
```

Shouldn't the first printed element be that None again?

Comment: That sounds reasonable. However if I access features via indexes I get *some*. sessionlayer[1] to [4] correspond to features with gml_ids 1 to 4. Higher elements again return None. The other features have gml_ids in the 1000s so the index do not correspond. I am fine with using next() but I would love to find out what really happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You weren't requesting the first feature, you were requesting a feature with an FID of "0" and your WFS doesn't have a feature with an FID of "0".

**Why:** 
The [`ogr.Layer.__getitem__`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/1.11/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/ogr.py#L2036) method which allows element and slice access, calls the [`ogr.Layer.GetFeature`](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/1.11/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/ogr.py#L1148) method. GetFeature fetches a feature by its identifier, not by its position.  This is intentional, so probably not a bug, but *is* quite unpythonic...

**Note:**
Iterating over features is [supposed to read them sequentially](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/1.11/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/ogr.py#L1205) but does not seem to...

**Example:**

```
from osgeo import ogr
ogr.UseExceptions() #I thought this **should** cause ogr to raise an exception when asking for a non-existent feature, but it doesn't...

#This is a public WFS
url = 'http://www.environment.gov.au/mapping/services/ogc_services/World_Heritage_Areas/MapServer/WFSServer'

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("WFS")
wfs_url = "WFS:"+url
wfs = driver.Open(wfs_url)
layer = wfs.GetLayerByIndex(0)

feat0 = layer[0]
print(feat0 is None)
# prints True

feat38 = layer[38]
print(feat38.GetFID())
# prints 38

for f in layer:
    print(f.GetFID())

# prints a very strange order...
# 38
# 39
# 40
# 1
# 2
# 3
# <snip 4-28>
# 29
# 30
# 31
# 41
# 42
# 43
# 44
# 45
# 46
# 32
# 33
# 34
# 35
# 36
# 37
```

Comment: Thank you! Are you sure it is all intentional? It seems very awkward and error-prone... I posted a follow-up at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/194377/how-do-i-get-the-feature-from-a-single-feature-ogr-layer-in-python-without-loopi on how to nicely get the single feature from a single-feature layer.