# How do I get the feature from a single-feature OGR layer in Python without looping?

Tags: python, ogr

A while ago [I asked why the 0 index in a OGR layer was not a feature and it turned out that OGR interprets the index as Feature ID and looks that up](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186012/why-is-the-first-element-of-my-wfs-layer-none-instead-of-a-feature).

Now I filtered a layer to have only one feature in it. I would like to use that feature straight-away but cannot figure out how.

The setup:

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("WFS")
wfs = driver.Open("WFS:https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WFS_Statistische_Gebiete?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS")  # This is a public WFS with open data
layer = wfs.GetLayerByName("Stadtteile")  # Some polygons, possibly multipolygons

# A random point inside one of them
point_in_hamburg = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt("POINT (566795 5935774)")

# Checking which features on layer intersect with our point
layer.SetSpatialFilter(point_in_hamburg)

# Due to the nature of Stadtteile (=districts) we
# will get only one intersecting feature:
print("One single feature: {}".format(len(layer) == 1))  # Prints "True"
```

Now I want to use that single feature. The only way I managed to is by using a loop over that length 1 layer:

```
for feature in layer:
    print(feature.GetFID())  # Prints "94"
```

I find that incredibly ugly and illogical. How can I directly access the feature instead without knowing anything about it?

`layer[0]` is not it. Strangely enough I can use `layer[94]` before the Spatial Filter and I get the feature (even though the WFS server returned a "Generic WFS service error") but if I try to use it afterwards, I get an [IndexError](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/1.11/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/ogr.py#L2059) from ogr. So even if the FID is 94 and is still 94 after filtering, `layer[94]` will fail at that point.

Is there some alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `layer.GetNextFeature()`

```
from osgeo import ogr

driver = ogr.GetDriverByName("WFS")
wfs = driver.Open("WFS:https://geodienste.hamburg.de/HH_WFS_Statistische_Gebiete?REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WFS")  # This is a public WFS with open data

layer = wfs.GetLayerByName("Stadtteile")  # Some polygons, possibly multipolygons

# A random point inside one of them
point_in_hamburg = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt("POINT (566795 5935774)")

# Checking which features on layer intersect with our point
layer.SetSpatialFilter(point_in_hamburg)

# Due to the nature of Stadtteile (=districts) we
# will get only one intersecting feature:
print("One single feature: {}".format(len(layer) == 1))  # Prints "True"

feature = layer.GetNextFeature()
print(feature.GetFID())  # Prints "94"
```

> I find that incredibly ugly and illogical.

I agree, but gdal/ogr is not a python library, it is a C++ library with python bindings. It is quite "unpythonic" and there are many "[gotchas](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/PythonGotchas)"

Comment: The `layer` instance doesn't "know" that there's only a single feature and doesn't read all of its features into Python objects, so it makes sense to require a "next" call. If you wanted to get your single result by using a `0` index, do it like: `feature = list(layer)[0]`.